# my matching game does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning JS and I'm making a game where I have to find the intruder.
my matching game does not work properly, because the faces on the left side must be incremetate of 5, because my code increases by 10?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Matching Game</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Aurora Ruggieri">
    
 <style>
  img{
     position: absolute;
     height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
 }
  
  div{
     position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
    }
 
 #rightSide { 
     left: 500px; 
        border-left: 1px solid black;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body onload="generateFaces()">
   <h1>Matching Game</h1>
   <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
   
   <div id="leftSide"></div>
   <div id="rightSide"></div>  
   
   <script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
 var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
 
    
 function generateFaces(){
   for (i= 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
     var top_position= Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
     var left_position= Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
  var leftSideImage = document.createElement("img");  
        leftSideImage.setAttribute("src", "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png");
  leftSideImage.style.top = top_position + "px";
        leftSideImage.style.left = left_position + "px";
     theLeftSide.appendChild(leftSideImage);
  var leftImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  leftImages.removeChild(leftImages.lastChild);
  theRightSide.appendChild(leftImages);
 }
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     
  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        while(theLeftSide.firstchild) {
   theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstchild);
  }
  while(theRightSide.firstchild) {
   theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstchild);
  }
  numberOfFaces += 5;
        generateFaces();
    };
 
     theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
        alert("Game Over!");
        theBody.onclick = null;
        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
    }; 
   } 
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kyle Richardson, thanks for the reply. The game has to increase by 5 faces whenever you find the intruder,next round will add 5 more, then 5 more...

Comment: If you take my suggestion and remove that line of code. This is exactly how it will work.

Comment: I just provided a snippet in my above answer so that you can see it work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to add 5 more faces each round, remove the following line of code:

```
numberOfFaces += 5;
```

How it works currently is, first round has 5 faces, next round will add 10 more, then 15 more, then 20 more, etc..

Run this provided snippet and you will see that removing that one line of code makes it work how you want.

```js
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
 var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
 
    
 function generateFaces(){
   for (i= 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
     var top_position= Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
     var left_position= Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
  var leftSideImage = document.createElement("img");  
        leftSideImage.setAttribute("src", "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png");
  leftSideImage.style.top = top_position + "px";
        leftSideImage.style.left = left_position + "px";
     theLeftSide.appendChild(leftSideImage);
  var leftImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  leftImages.removeChild(leftImages.lastChild);
  theRightSide.appendChild(leftImages);
 }
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     
  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        while(theLeftSide.firstchild) {
   theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstchild);
  }
  while(theRightSide.firstchild) {
   theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstchild);
  }
        generateFaces();
    };
 
     theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
        alert("Game Over!");
        theBody.onclick = null;
        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
    }; 
   }
   
   generateFaces();
```

```css
  img{
     position: absolute;
     height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
 }
  
  div{
     position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
    }
 
 #rightSide { 
     left: 500px; 
        border-left: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
   <h1>Matching Game</h1>
   <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
   
   <div id="leftSide"></div>
   <div id="rightSide"></div>
```